# webapp - take a snapshot with phone main camera by one click

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-applications, android-camera

I really want it to take a snapshot and send it to the server by just one click (once cam access approved for the website) or by just opening the link. I have accomplished that by taking a snapshot of a videostream of the html5 video element - see example. However, the quality is webcam video stream snapshot quality.

How do I really take an actual foto with proper quality?
Must only run on android.

btw:

```
<input id="myFileInput1" class="button" type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```

is not an option, since it requires clicking, (choosing cam), open camera, taking picture, approving pic

```
<body style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="display:none;">
        <video id="player" autoplay></video>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; margin: 0 auto;">
        <canvas id="canvas" width=853 height=1280></canvas>
    </div>

    <script>
        const player = document.getElementById('player');
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        //8833ee7a5bcb161baa10970d674b8b003e769c40c452ed7ad7e31d235f0825c1

        const constraints = {
        video: { 
            optional: [{sourceId: "46884cf8fc3dc74cdefa932000380ae5d85b863a502428115bbdeb5d784be233"}]
        },
        };

        setTimeout(() => {
        context.drawImage(player, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // Stop all video streams.
        player.srcObject.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
        }, 1500);


        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
        .then((stream) => {
            // Attach the video stream to the video element and autoplay.
            player.srcObject = stream;
        });
    </script>
```